this.resolveComponent is not a function
I'm building an application with Laravel + React. I use Inertia.js to combine the two. The project was generated through Vite.js, which is also used.
I now have built a table, which is responsive so I can make changes to it and these changes should be saved to the database when I click save. This works, however, I keep getting the error this.resolveComponent is not a function whenever the table should be re-rendered. It seems that I cannot re-render components for some reason and I tried everything I can think of.
app.jsx
import './bootstrap';
import '../css/app.css';

import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/react';
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';

const appName = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_NAME || 'Laravel';
createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.jsx`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.jsx')),
    setup({ el, App, props }) {
        const root = createRoot(el);

        root.render(<App {...props} />);
    },
    progress: {
        color: '#4B5563',
    },
});

Can you guys give me any advice? I cannot seem to fix this and there is not much online about this issue either.

Alright, I don't know what I did wrong, but I decided to create a clean Laravel/React/InertiaJS (+ Laravel Breeze for the auth stuff) stack using Vite and then moved all my code over to the new project. I suppose something was wrong with my project, as of now it works perfectly.
If anyone ever wants to try the same solution, here are the commands I used to build a new project (these instructions were generated using ChatGPT):

Install Laravel:
Ensure you have Composer installed, then create a new Laravel project.
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel myshop
cd myshop



2. Install Laravel Breeze

Install Laravel Breeze:
Laravel Breeze provides a minimal implementation of all of Laravel's authentication features using Blade. Since we want to use React with InertiaJS, we need the React preset.
composer require laravel/breeze --dev
php artisan breeze:install react


Install & Build Frontend Assets:
npm install && npm run dev



3. Install Laravel InertiaJS

Install InertiaJS Server-side:
composer require inertiajs/inertia-laravel


Install Inertia Middleware:
After installation, register the middleware in your App\Http\Kernel.php file:
'web' => [
    // Other middleware...
    \App\Http\Middleware\HandleInertiaRequests::class,
],



4. Setup Vite with React and InertiaJS

Install Client-side Dependencies with Vite:
npm install @inertiajs/react @vitejs/plugin-react vite axios


Configure Vite:
Replace contents of your vite.config.js with:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js'),
        },
    },
    server: {
        watch: {
            usePolling: true,
        },
    },
});



5. Setup Inertia React Components

Update Resources JS Structure:
Create folders for your React components if they don't already exist:
mkdir -p resources/js/Pages resources/js/Components
touch resources/js/Pages/Dashboard.jsx resources/js/Pages/Login.jsx


Create an app.jsx entry point:
In resources/js, create app.jsx:
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/react';
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress';
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';

createInertiaApp({
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(
        `./Pages/${name}.jsx`,
        import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.jsx')
    ),
    setup({ el, App, props }) {
        render(<App {...props} />, el);
    },
});

InertiaProgress.init();



6. Update Laravel Blade View

Add Main Inertia View:
Update resources/views/app.blade.php or create it:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title inertia>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>
        @viteReactRefresh
        @vite('resources/js/app.jsx')
        @inertiaHead
    </head>
    <body class="font-sans antialiased">
        @inertia
    </body>
</html>



7. Run Migrations and Build Project

Run Migrations:
php artisan migrate


Run the Development Server:
php artisan serve
npm run dev



8. Setup Inertia Links in Laravel Breeze

Update Auth Components:
Ensure that your Breeze auth components use Inertia for navigation. You can wrap form submissions in a useForm hook from Inertia, for instance. For example, in your Login.jsx:
import React from 'react';
import { useForm } from '@inertiajs/react';

export default function Login() {
    const { data, setData, post } = useForm({
        email: '',
        password: '',
        remember: false,
    });

    const submit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        post(route('login'));
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={submit}>
            {/* Your form fields */}
        </form>
    );
}




